# Jquery: Pass value to next field in array format fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[depart][]" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[return][]" />
</div>
```

Then I have the user clicking on a more button and the div above being cloned, and appended below it.

My question is:

How can I have the value of `booking[depart][n]` being equal to `booking[return][n-1]` everytime the elements are duplicated. (where `n` is just the number representing the index of the input in the field array).

**EDIT**

The expected html(if I change the id of the cloned div, but an answer concentrating on the name attributes would be prefarable)

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[depart][]" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[return][]" />
</div>
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker0">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[depart][]" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[return][]" />
</div>
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[depart][]" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[return][]" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of expected HTML output for new elements.

Comment: @halfzebra Please check edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) will copy the values, so we will have to update them manually.

My approach is suitable for this single use-case, but I would recommend to use some data-binding MVC library to separate your data from the DOM. It's getting really hard with jQuery, if you want to validate user input.

Please consider the following snippet:

```js
// Wait for DOMReady.
$(function() {
  var lastId = null,
      count = 0,
      
      // Put everything in to variables for optimal usage.
      $target = $('body'),
      $btn = $('#btn');

  $btn.on('click', function() {
    
    // Clone the object.
    var $cloneEl = (lastId !== null) ? $('#' + lastId).clone() : $('#datepicker').clone();
        $returnEl = $cloneEl.find('input[name="booking[return][]"]'),
        $departEl = $cloneEl.find('input[name="booking[depart][]"]');
    
    if ($returnEl.val() !== '') {
      $departEl.val($returnEl.val());
      $returnEl.val('');
    } else {
      $departEl.val('');
    }
    
    lastId = $cloneEl.attr('id') + count;
    
    // Update the "id" attribute and insert in to <body>
    $cloneEl.attr('id', lastId).appendTo($target);
    
    count++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Add new input group</button>
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[depart][]" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="booking[return][]" />
</div>
```

Comment: @AceMure1thi this was the part that I didn't get from the question, please see the updated version.